# Como verificar quantas vezes aparece o número 2 dentro de uma matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu objetivo neste algoritmo é encontrar quantas vezes aparece o número 2 dentro de uma matriz 8x3.

Meu resultado até o momento está assim:

```
from collections import Counter
import time
import numpy as np

m = int(input('Quantas linas? '))
n = int(input('Quantas colunas? '))

input("Será aceito somente números entre -20 e 10.\n ... \nPrecione a tecla ENTER para continuar!\n")
time.sleep(2)

matrizA = list()
for c in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                valor = int(input(f'Digite o {i}º elemento da {c}ª linha: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
        linha.append(valor)
    matrizA.append(linha)

matriz = np.array(matrizA)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz gerada é:\n{matriz}\033[m')

c = Counter(matrizA)
print(c[2])
```

Eu consegui fazer a matriz e tentei usar o `import Counter` para retornar o resultado da repetição do número 2 dentro da matriz. Porém o resultado não saiu como eu queria.

Answer (score 2):

Sua `matrizA` é na verdade uma lista de listas: é uma lista na qual cada elemento é outra lista (e essas sim tem números).

Então basta percorrer as "linhas" (na verdade, as listas), e depois percorrer os elementos de cada linha e ver se o valor é 2:

```
cont = 0
for linha in matrizA:
    for num in linha:
        if num == 2:
            cont += 1
```

Mas para obter a contagem de um único elemento você também pode usar o método `count`:

```
cont = 0
for linha in matrizA:
    cont += linha.count(2)
```

E por fim, pode usar `sum` (que soma uma série de valores) juntamente com uma  [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
cont = sum(linha.count(2) for linha in matrizA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a biblioteca `numpy`, por exemplo:

```
np.count_nonzero(matriz == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço muito de bibliotecas Python, mas se o seu objetivo for apenas descobrir quantas vezes um determinado número aparece dentro de uma matriz, você pode criar a função abaixo;

```py
def Repete(matriz, identificador):
    repetiu = 0
    for indice in range(0, len(matriz)):
        repetiu+=1 if matriz[indice] == identificador else repetiu

    return repetiu
```

Espero que isso tenha ajudado de alguma forma.